# i want to scroll an Image in HTML without using <marquee> tag.... with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, dynamic, scroll

i just want to give dynamic effect to Image in javascript...but without using of marquee

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why everybody hates the `<marquee>` tag.

That being said, try:

http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_scroller/ *(demo)*
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqScroller

http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/example/left/ *(demo)*
http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/example/

http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html *(demo)*
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

This one doesn't require jQuery:

http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/left/ *(demo)*
http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/

Answer (score -1):

Add this below script in `<head>` tag

```
<head> 
    <script src="assets/js/crawler.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
```

And then add following code in `<script>` tag

```
 marqueeInit({
                   uniqueid: 'mycrawler2',
                   style: {

                   },
                   inc: 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
                   mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
                   moveatleast: 2, 
                   neutral: 150,
                   savedirection: true,
                   random: true
                });
```

After this you have to add an `ID` in the `<div>` tag

```
<div id="mycrawler2">
            <img src="assets/images/products/img1.png" />
            <img src="assets/images/products/img2.png" />
            <img src="assets/images/products/img3.png" />
            <img src="assets/images/products/img4.png" />
            <img src="assets/images/products/img5.png" />
            <img src="assets/images/products/img6.png" />
    </div>
```

It will apply a marquee effect to images and they will move continuously.

Comment: Roberrrt dont mark it negative just because i didnt edit that nicely...but my answer is right